# Do any other scriptures mention Brahma Tirtha, bathing where non-Brahmins become Brahmins?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, caste-system, brahmins, pilgrimage

Mahabharat, Vana parva, tirtha-yatra parva https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-third-book/d/doc7362.html. Says:

> One should next proceed to the excellent tirtha of Brahma. **Bathing there, a person, of the (three) inferior orders, obtaineth the status of a Brahmana**, and if one be a Brahmana, his soul being purified from every sin, he attaineth to the highest state.

Do any other scriptures mention this particular property of Brahma tirtha?

Comment: Good question @Aks

Comment: Similar mention is in Skanda purana also...

Answer (score 7):

**Yes**.

The property of Brahma Tirtha : *bestowing Brahman-hood after a holy bath* has been mentioned in other scriptures such as Narada Purana.

In a conversation between Vasu and Mohini, Vasu tells about this special property of Brahma tirtha

> **By taking a holy dip in the Brahma Tirtha a man obtains Brahmana-hood**.
> This is the greatest spot of Brahma. By going there none comes to
> grief.
>
> [[102, 65: Pilgrimage to Kuruksetra, Uttarabhaga, Narada Purana]](https://archive.org/details/dli.bengal.10689.12978/page/n227/mode/2up)

Comment: Where exactly is this place located? In Kurukshetra?

Comment: It is in Sawant, Karnal https://48koskurukshetra.com/brahma-tirth-sawant/#

Comment: @Rickross ...........................................

Comment: Yeah thanks .. so its there in the Sawant village.

Comment: Yeah...........

Comment: So caste can be changed in the same birth just by bathing here?? It mostly means that it helps get Brahmin birth in future, not in the same birth. If not everyone would have bathed there.